# Not getting firebase notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

i have an issue with my taxi app android project.all the features works fine, but when customer request a ride, the driver not getting notification. but driver can see the pending request by go to pending activity by manually, and database storing all data in firebase. and also when i test sending message through firebase cloud messaging i'm get notification for both driver and customer app. but when i test both driver and customer app itself rides request not getting any notification. any one can help me out to solve this issues?

```
MyFirebaseMessagingService.java 

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
public static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData());
}

private void sendNotification(Map<String, String> data) {

    int num = ++NOTIFICATION_ID;
    Bundle msg = new Bundle();
    for (String key : data.keySet()) {
        Log.e(key, data.get(key));
        msg.putString(key, data.get(key));
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    if (msg.containsKey("action")) {
        intent.putExtra("action", msg.getString("action"));
    }
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, num /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle(msg.getString("title"))
            .setContentText(msg.getString("msg"))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(num, notificationBuilder.build());
}

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer">
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<application
    android:name="com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer.custom.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/splash1"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_android_map_api_key" />

    <activity android:name="com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer.acitivities.SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity

android:name="com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer.acitivities.LoginActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

    <activity 
android:name="com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer.acitivities.HomeActivity" />

    <service
        android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService"
        android:exported="false" />

    <activity 
android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity" />
    <activity 
android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.LoginActivity" />
    <activity 
android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentMethodActivity" />
    <activity 
android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalFuturePaymentActivity" />
    <activity 

<service android:name=
"com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer.Server.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" 
/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

<service 
 android:name=
"com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer.Server.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">


<intent-filter>
<action 
android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
</intent-filter>
</service>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/icon" />

    <meta-data

android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/hint" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat after request a ride from customer app

```
09-19 17:30:25.730 1049-1049/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer 
D/ViewRootImpl@44dc853[HomeActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
09-19 17:30:25.842 1049-1049/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer 
D/ViewRootImpl@44dc853[HomeActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
09-19 17:30:25.903 1049-1049/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer E/apikey: 
a0igPB0w146865636K8aKoF257487585
09-19 17:30:25.949 1049-1049/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer D/server: 
http://www.vanitt.co.uk/Dashboard/api/user/addRide/format/json
09-19 17:30:25.989 1049-1049/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer 
D/ViewRootImpl@44dc853[HomeActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0] 
[1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x1 surface={valid=true 
531651338240} changed=false
09-19 17:30:26.560 1049-1049/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer 
V/AsyncHttpRH: Progress 257 from 194 (132%)
09-19 17:30:26.590 1049-1049/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer W/JsonHttpRH: 
onSuccess(int, Header[], JSONObject) was not overriden, but callback 
was received
09-19 17:30:26.666 1049-1049/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer 
D/ViewRootImpl@deac048[Toast]: setView = 
android.widget.LinearLayout{339fee1 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} TM=true 
MM=false
09-19 17:30:26.669 1049-1049/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer V/Toast: 
Text: Side in android.widget.Toast$TN@e604406
09-19 17:30:26.672 1049-1049/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer 
D/ViewRootImpl@deac048[Toast]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
09-19 17:30:26.702 1049-1049/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer V/Surface: 
sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
09-19 17:30:26.708 1049-1049/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer 
D/ViewRootImpl@deac048[Toast]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][0,0] new= 
[231,1596][849,1728] result=0x7 surface={valid=true 531639455744} 
changed=true
09-19 17:30:26.743 1049-1049/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer 
D/ViewRootImpl@deac048[Toast]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(231, 1596 
- 849, 1728) ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
09-19 17:30:26.930 1049-1049/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer 
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 
13280021
09-19 17:30:27.209 1049-1049/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer D/Network: 
Network
09-19 17:30:27.346 1049-1133/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer I/System.out: 
(HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
09-19 17:30:27.355 1049-1133/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer I/System.out: 
(HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
09-19 17:30:27.402 1049-1131/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer I/System.out: 
(HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
09-19 17:30:27.404 1049-1131/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer I/System.out: 
(HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
09-19 17:30:27.409 1049-1049/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer 
I/Choreographer: Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too 
much work on its main thread.
09-19 17:30:27.435 1049-1049/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer 
D/ViewRootImpl@44dc853[HomeActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0] 
[1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x1 surface={valid=true 
531651338240} changed=false
09-19 17:30:27.444 1049-1049/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer V/Surface: 
sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
09-19 17:30:27.455 1049-5286/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer V/Surface: 
sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
09-19 17:30:27.456 1049-5286/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer 
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, 
EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format 
*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1080x1680]-format:2
09-19 17:30:27.507 1049-1049/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer E/server: 

09-19 17:30:27.805 1049-1049/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer W/JsonHttpRH: 
onSuccess(int, Header[], JSONObject) was not overriden, but callback 
was received
09-19 17:30:27.809 1049-1049/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer E/log: 
{"status":"success","fair":{"cost":"5","unit":"$2"},"data": 
 [{"user_id":"2","name":"prinsdriver","email":"test@gmail.com",
"latitude":"5
1.4533739","longitude":"-2.131E- 
4","vehicle_info":"","distance":"0.00013425232662457948"}]}
09-19 17:30:28.397 1049-1060/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer I/zygote64: 
NativeAllocBackground concurrent copying GC freed 36395(2MB) AllocSpace 
objects, 53(3MB) LOS objects, 50% free, 13MB/26MB, paused 863us total 
472.437ms
09-19 17:30:29.749 1049-1060/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer I/zygote64: 
NativeAllocBackground concurrent copying GC freed 18505(644KB) 
AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 13MB/26MB, paused 
754us total 378.443ms
09-19 17:30:30.133 1049-1049/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer 
D/ViewRootImpl@deac048[Toast]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
09-19 17:30:30.135 1049-1049/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer 
D/InputEventReceiver: channel 'e2bfa7c Toast (client)' ~ Disposing 
input event receiver.
09-19 17:30:30.136 1049-1049/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer 
D/InputEventReceiver: channel 'e2bfa7c Toast (client)' 
 ~NativeInputEventReceiver.
 09-19 17:30:33.182 1049-1132/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer 
  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
  09-19 17:30:33.185 1049-1132/com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer 
  I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
```

MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java

```
private static final String TAG = "firebase token";

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {

    final String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.

    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    SessionManager.getInstance().setGcmToken(token);
    Server.setHeader(SessionManager.getInstance().getKEY());
    params.put("user_id", SessionManager.getInstance().getUid());
    params.put("gcm_token", token);
    Server.postSync("api/user/update/format/json", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
            super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseString, throwable);
            Log.d(TAG, responseString);
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: if you are getting notifications from fcm panel but not after hitting web services then it must be something wrong from backend side. Please check your server key and client key registration in backend

Comment: Did you override `onNewToken(String token)` method in your MyFirebaseMessagingService class?

Comment: added FirebaseInstanceIDService

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially make sure that FCM has been integrated in your server side implementation to send the notification to the driver app (to a particular firebase registeration token for that driver). And if yes , then make sure what type of [message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) you are getting from the server and then apply the required code in the `FirebaseMessagingService` class to obtain the that message type(since its different for each type).

With FCM, you can send two types of messages to clients:

1.Notification messages, sometimes thought of as "display messages." These are handled by the FCM SDK automatically.

2.Data messages, which are handled by the client app.

the following code can get the both the cases:-

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

// Check if message contains a data payload.
if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

    if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
        // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use Firebase Job Dispatcher.
        scheduleJob();
    } else {
        // Handle message within 10 seconds
        handleNow();
    }

}

// Check if message contains a notification payload.
if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}

// Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
// message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
}
```

Comment: project included FirebaseInstanceIDService

Answer (score 0):

There are nothing wrong with my code i changed different device to test and getting all the notification, so problem with the device.

Answer (score -2):

You forgot to override`onNewToken(String token)` method in your `MyFirebaseMessagingService` class.

That method will give you FCM token, which will be used by your server to send notifications to diver app.

Follow this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client), it has a detailed step by step explanation to set up client apps to receive notifications from the server.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20906773)

Comment: @MJM thank you for pointing that. I have changed my answer with the actual fix that the implementation is missing.